# Custom property of a custom control not being set - xamarin forms

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms, custom-controls, inotifypropertychanged, custom-renderer

I'm trying to create a custom entry control with EntryType property which I then use inside custom renderers to set platform specific values. But the EntryType is never set when used from Xaml. Here's my code:

```
public class ExtendedEntry : Xamarin.Forms.Entry
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty EntryTypeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "EntryType",
        returnType: typeof(int),
        declaringType: typeof(EntryTextType),
        defaultValue: 1
        );

    public EntryTextType EntryType
    {
        get
        {
            return (EntryTextType)GetValue(EntryTypeProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(EntryTypeProperty, value);

        }
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        if (propertyName == EntryTypeProperty.PropertyName)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public enum EntryTextType
{
    Any,
    Numeric,
    Url,
    Email
}
```

---

```
public class ExtendedEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    public ExtendedEntryRenderer(Android.Content.Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var element = (ExtendedEntry)Element;
            Control.Hint = element.Placeholder;
            switch(element.EntryType)
            {
                case EntryTextType.Numeric:
                    Control.SetRawInputType(Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var p = e.PropertyName;
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    }

}
```

And then in XAML, I use the control as this:

```
<controls:ExtendedEntry Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True" Text="{Binding Secret}" EntryType="Any"/>
```

The problem is, **EntryType never gets set to EntryTextType.Any**, and always uses the default value of EntryTextType.Numeric. What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed some discrepancies in the `EntryTypeProperty` declaration.

- Declaring type should be the owner which is `ExtendedEntry`
- And, to instruct XAML to use the enum `TypeConverter`, you will have to define the datatype as `EntryTextType`

So your new code will look like:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty EntryTypeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: "EntryType",
    returnType: typeof(EntryTextType),
    declaringType: typeof(ExtendedEntry),
    defaultValue: EntryTextType.Numeric
    );
```

Comment: the default value gets set even with integer value 1. The problem is, the value assigned in xaml never gets set. So, even with above xaml, EntryType is always Numeric.

Comment: I just tested with the new property - it is being set as `Any` (so I am not able to reproduce your issue)

Comment: But when I changed the `returnType` back to `int` the value was not set through XAML. As I mentioned in the answer you have to instruct the XAML processor to use the `TypeConverter` for enums - the easiest way to do that is by setting the `returnType` to right type.

Comment: ohhh...give me a min to verify. I can't believe I didn't try setting it to the right type even once.